# Check with wildcard if WordPress database's wp_posts contains specific text and if so output unique results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

There are almost the same pieces of text used in different posts, they are always start and end with the same words and only their middle part is different.

For example they are *"It has started **in the `beginning` of the day"*** in one post, *"It has finished **in the `middle` of the day"*** in another post and *"It hasn't started **in the `beginning` of the day"*** in a third one.

How could I output a list like

> 1. in the beginning of the day
> 2. in the middle of the day

on a given page by querying the wp_posts table with **in the `wildcard` of the day** and skipping repeated results?

I **do not** need to find posts that contain the search results, I need to output exactly the search results themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be fast.

```
 SELECT id, post_title 
   FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '% in the % of the day %'
    AND post_type = 'post'
```

If you're implementing a search function, you might look at plugins for the purpose; there are some decently good search plugins.

Comment: No, I'm not implementing a search function, I just need to list some predefined pieces of text with some small variations if this text appears in any WordPress post. Will this query be a bit faster if limit it by a specific WP category?